# Does Django Channels work as intended as a WSGI app?

Tags: django, django-channels

I am trying to implement Django Channels because I need to have users receive notifications when another user does something, and I am completely confused by this part:

http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html

> Deploying applications using channels requires a few more steps than a
>   normal Django WSGI application, but you have a couple of options as to
>   how to deploy it and how much of your traffic you wish to route
>   through the channel layers.
>
> Firstly, remember that it’s an entirely optional part of Django. If
>   you leave a project with the default settings (no CHANNEL_LAYERS),
>   it’ll just run and work like a normal WSGI app.

The problem is that I have quite limited rights on the shared hosting that I am using and therefore, I can't use the runworker command.

The quote above says that this part is "optional" and that without it, it'll work like a normal WSGI app. But can I use Django Channels with a normal WSGI app? If not, then doesn't that mean that it's not optional at all?

So my question is: if I skip this part, will the channels still work and will I be able to use the things showed on this page (routing, sending messages, etc): http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html ?

Comment: I'd guess this is just a leftover piece of documentation from the time when Channels was still aimed to be included in Django core. This part [hasn't been updated](https://github.com/django/channels/commits/master/docs/deploying.rst) since that decision was changed. In that context it makes a lot more sense. I don't think you can actually use Channels features if you don't use the new setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the docs, what i get is, first you need to use a back end to run channel eg. redis, Sharding, and run "runworker", but since it's not an option for you, have a look at this http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/backends.html

"""The in-memory layer is only useful when running the protocol server and the worker server in a single process; the most common case of this is runserver, where a server thread, this channel layer, and worker thread all co-exist inside the same python process.""" 
So by avoiding third party backend you can use in-memory asgi layer and just run 'runserver' and the channel layer is setup. Just look for in-memory subtopic in the link

And if you keep the CHANNEL_LAYERS empty django'll work as a wsgi app, but what we need is asgi app, and asgi is required for channels.